# C# Saving to Access. Confusion

Tags: c#, ms-access, save, saving-data

I'm confused about the way my code is working after researching a way to save data to an Access Database. The program writes the code into the Database successfully, I know this because in the same run of the program that data is present.

My confusion is due to how I can't seem to find a way to Save the Database so that whenever the program runs again the data remains. What happens at the moment is after the program writes to the database, if I stop debugging and start it again any data that was added isn't present any more.

I may be being dense but can't tell myself so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection();
Conn.ConnectionString = 
  @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\HoliPlanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
```

Comment: Where is your Access database located? Please show us your connection string.

Comment: I've added the connection string to the Question above, please take a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running a local database. Click on the database in the solution explorer and set the CopyToOutput Directory to something other than Copy Always. Copy Always copies your template to the application folder every time the application is ran. Copy If Newer will copy the database template only if you have made schema changes but again, you will lose any data. Never copy will ensure that you maintain your data but you would need to apply any schema changes to the working database in the application folder manually.

Comment: I have changed the property to NeverCopy but now I'm being told my Connection String is incorrect? Why is this, do you know?

Comment: Check your bin/debug or bin/release folder (depending on how your set to compile) and make sure that there is indeed a copy of the database there. Can you give the exact error that you're receiving?

Comment: How would I check whether I need a copy in bin/debug or bin/release? 
Heres the error : Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\j.perry\Desktop\ProjectHolidayPlans\ProjectHolidayPlans\bin\Debug\HoliPlanData.accdb'.

Comment: follow that path. It's saying that HoliPlanData.accdb is not located in your Debug folder. You should have a copy of the database in your solution folder that will need manually copied into the Debug folder when you set never copy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Charles. I have copied the file into the debug folder and everything works exactly how I'd have hoped. Thank you again, have a great day.